# Google Apps Script: "Range is not a function, it is object" error when trying to put a comment in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

After run a script, I'm trying to put a comment in the first cell of the selected row. I'm using this code to do this:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var firstCell = activeCell.offset(0, 1-activeCell.getColumn());
  firstCell().setComment(docName);
```

(where `docName` is a string)
However, I got this error message: `TypeError: Range is not a function, it is object.` 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is explicit... firstCell is a range object, you shouldn't use parenthesis.

Try simply like this:  `firstCell.setComment(docName);`